# How to retrieve web service values through Retrofit to text view?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm developing an app and in first activity it has card view layout. I'm retrieving data from a webservice and relevant data are showed in card view. It's working well. Now when a user clicks a particular card view I need to go for another activity. I'm getting relevant ID for that card view and passing it to the second activity. In second activity I  need to show the content according to that unique Id. But I'm not getting any thing. This is what I tried.

Pojo class

```
public class PromoDetails {

String PromoId;
String PromoName;
String PromoImg;
String promoDetails;
String promoValidty;

public PromoDetails(String PromoId, String PromoName, String PromoImg , String promoDetails , String promoValidity) {
    this.PromoId = PromoId;
    this.PromoName = PromoName;
    this.PromoImg = PromoImg;
    this.promoDetails = promoDetails;
    this.promoValidty = promoValidity;
}



public String getPromoId() {
    return PromoId;
}

public void setPromoId(String promoId) {
    PromoId = promoId;
}

public String getPromoName() {
    return PromoName;
}

public void setPromoName(String promoName) {
    PromoName = promoName;
}

public String getPromoImg() {
    return PromoImg;
}

public void setPromoImg(String promoImg) {
    PromoImg = promoImg;
}

public String getPromoDetails() {
    return promoDetails;
}

public void setPromoDetails(String promoDetails) {
    this.promoDetails = promoDetails;
}

public String getPromoValidty() {
    return promoValidty;
}

public void setPromoValidty(String promoValidty) {
    this.promoValidty = promoValidty;
}}
```

ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiInterface {


@POST("ap/promotions.php")
Call<List<Promotions>> getPromotions();

@GET("test.php/promotions/{PromoId}")
Call<List<PromoDetails>> getPromotDetails(@Path("PromoId") String PromoId) ;}
```

New Activity class

```
public class PromotionsInside extends Activity {


private ApiInterface apiInterface;
private List<PromoDetails> promoDetails;
TextView prDescription;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.promo_inside);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     String promoId = "";

    if (extras != null) {
        promoId = extras.getString("PROMO_ID");


      getPromotionUpdate(promoId);
    }

}


private void getPromotionUpdate(String myPromoId) {


    apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);


    Call<List<PromoDetails>> call = apiInterface.getPromotDetails(myPromoId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<PromoDetails>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<PromoDetails>> call, Response<List<PromoDetails>> response) {
            promoDetails = response.body();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

 prDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.promoDescriptionsss) ;
 prDescription.setText(promoDetails.get(0).getPromoName());
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<PromoDetails>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}}
```

Comment: Try with debugger, does your extras has some value? If it hasn't, the getPromotionUpdate() never gets called

Comment: can you show us where you are creating the intent?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if you actually get to the getPromotionUpdate() method?

Comment: Extras has values , I checked it.

Comment: And does `promoID` get a correct value?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti promoID gets the value. I think it's with the getPromotionUpdate method inside. please help

Comment: I think the problem is that you have the same call to the API, with different signature, try removing `@GET("test.php/promotions/{promoId}")
Call<List<PromoDetails>> getPromotDetails();` from the interface, as it has no sense, you're saying to the URL that you're passing a id, but you're not

Comment: Very sorry. It was my mistake. I have updated it too.. But nothing happens

Comment: Does the debugger get into the `onResponse()` method? If so, what is the value of `promoDetails.get(0).getPromoName()`?

Comment: @Robert Ruxandrescu It's not going to onResponse :( Both get null values.

Comment: If it does not reach on response you might have some problems in `apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);`

Comment: Hm... this makes me think about some time when I had similar problems... it looks as if it never gets into the onResponse() method but it does. Since Retrofit works in a different thread when it makes the call, maybe that's why you don't see the debugger get into the method?

I don't remember exactly. Let me check my code.

Comment: Thank you very much @RobertRuxandrescu. Please help me to fix this

Comment: Ok, I checked - it reaches onResponse() in my application. Have you tried to put a breakpoint at the line where you have the `promoDetails = response.body();` code? See if it stops at that breakpoint when you debug your app.

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu- it doesn't get into  public void onResponse(Call<List<PromoDetails>> call, Response<List<PromoDetails>> response)

Comment: Have you tried putting the breakpoint exactly where I told you?

Comment: Does the `getPromotions()` method work correctly? If so, can you check if your server returns the right type of objects? In other words, can you check that the JSON (I'm assuming you get a JSON) that you're receiving from the endpoint is of the right type? For example, try to make a request to your server's endpoint for the JSON from the browser, and see what you get in the browser.

Then try to convert the JSON that you get to a POJO and see if you get the right type of POJO. From what I remember, if you don't get EXACTLY the correct type of POJOs in the JSON, Retrofit won't work.

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu I checked all. But no changes

Comment: @venura can u post expect response ?

Comment: "PromoId":"1","PromoName":"50% Off for Medium Pizzas.","Category":"FOODS & DRINKS","PromoImg":"https:\/\/androidsra.000webhostapp.com\/img_ap\/pizza_promo.png","promoDetails":"abc def","promoValidty":"31st October 2017 ","companyId":"1"

Comment: I don't know why, but I have a feeling this has to have some very simple explanation. There's something simple we're all missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar case. Try to use this to start second activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PromotionsInside.class);
//Make sure that you put String id in intent
    intent.putExtra("PROMO_ID", id);

    startActivity(intent);
```

And this in second activity:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("PROMO_ID")) {
        String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("PROMO_ID", null);
        //next steps that you need
    }
```

Hope it will help you